# How to use ? : if statements with Razor and inline code blocks

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, razor

I'm updating my old .aspx views with the new Razore view engine. I have a bunch of places where I have code like this:

```
<span class="vote-up<%= puzzle.UserVote == VoteType.Up ? "-selected" : "" %>">Vote Up</span>
```

Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
<span class="vote-up@{puzzle.UserVote == VoteType.Up ? "-selected" : ""}">Vote Up</span>
```

However there's two problems here:

1. `vote-up@{puzzle.UserVote` .... is not treating the @ symbol as a start of a code block
2. `@puzzle.UserVote == VoteType.Up` looks at the first part `@puzzle.UserVote` as if it's supposed to render the value of the variable.

Anyone know how to address these issues?

Comment: I haven't used Razor but based on what I'm seeing, try `@(puzzle.UserVote == VoteType.Up ? "-selected" : "")`

Comment: As this is the top result for inline ternary operators in razor, I'll add that if your output contains html or encodable characters such as apostrophes, e.g. `@(isSomething ? "class='test'" : "")` for example injecting javascript or similar, it will encode them as entities like `&#39;` and break the page. So you must use `Html.Raw("..")`. Otherwise with the above code you'd end up with something like `<p class=&#39;test&#39;>` which is invalid.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

This should work:

```
<span class="vote-up@(puzzle.UserVote == VoteType.Up ? "-selected" : "")">Vote Up</span>
```

Comment: very strange to use the paren rather then the brace

Answer (score 57):

```
@( condition ? "true" : "false" )
```

Comment: I went for this one, feels clean and is easy to read back later

Comment: If you need to display the value of a property (including a string) rather than calling ToString() - Which didn't work in my case. You can do this @(condition ? $"{foo.bar}" : "Default")

Answer (score 32):

The key is to encapsulate the expression in parentheses after the @ delimiter. You can make any compound expression work this way.

Answer (score 10):

In most cases [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770655/56984) of [CD..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139300/cd) will work perfectly fine. However I had a bit more twisted situation:

```
 @(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MaidenName) ? "&nbsp;" : Model.MaidenName)
```

This would print me "&nbsp;" in my page, respectively generate the source `&amp;nbsp;`. Now there is a function `Html.Raw("&nbsp;")` which is supposed to let you write source code, except in this constellation it throws a compiler error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot
>   be determined because there is no implicit conversion between
>   'System.Web.IHtmlString' and 'string'

So I ended up writing a statement like the following, which is less nice but works even in my case:

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MaidenName)) { @Html.Raw("&nbsp;") } else { @Model.MaidenName }
```

Note: interesting thing is, once you are inside the curly brace, you have to restart a Razor block.

Comment: Why not just `@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MaidenName) ? Html.Raw("&nbsp;") : Model.MaidenName)`

Comment: Uhm.. how about because of the aforementioned Compiler Error ? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I need more coffee :)

Comment: You can avoid that error by making both sides of the ternary operator the same type, `@(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MaidenName) ? Html.Raw("&nbsp;") : Html.Raw(Model.MaidenName))`