# How to add some class to div element, depending of some condition in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm quite confused in Razor syntax ))) For example I have an element:

```
<div class="category-block">

</div>
```

I have a parameter

`string viewMode = Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["view"];`

and I need to add `list-block` class to my div element with class `category-block` and to get

```
<div class="category-block list-block">

</div>
```

**if**

`viewMode != null && viewMode.Equals("list", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

I trie to do something like:

```
<div class="category-block @(viewMode != null && viewMode.Equals("list", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ? list-block : string.Empty ">
```

but every time I get a lot of syntax errors... I don't know is it possible to write something inside opened attribure brackets;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ? : if statements with Razor and inline code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770605/how-to-use-if-statements-with-razor-and-inline-code-blocks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your final ) in the wrong place. Also, you need to add quotes around `list-block`.

```
<div class="category-block @(viewMode != null && viewMode.Equals("list", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "list-block" : string.Empty)">
```

Also, if you're going to be doing a lot of string comparison in the view like that, I'd recommend creating a helper method so that you don't have to use the verbose `string.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` every time.